# Saving user's previous search queries

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, indexeddb

How can I do that?

To start with, planning to save it into the HTML5 local database using `IndexedDB`? May be later on I can save it the user's table in the database.
Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

if they will be using the search on multiple devices save it on the server side. that way they get their complete search history. if not go with local.

do not forget to have a mechanism to purge the search queries on a user action.

Answer (score 0):

Indexeddb is not design for that kind of usage. It is better of with usual http caching.

Indexeddb is design for storing full table and query client side itself.

Comment: Why `IndexedDB` is not a good idea? How would I use `HTTP caching` to store search queries